# Which dependent variable is mostly impacted by predictor?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, predictive-models, goodness-of-fit

Usually one wants to identify the most important predictors (*x1, x2, x3..., xn*) in a regression model. My question is reversed: I have a data set that contains a risk factor *risk* and several outcomes *y1, y2, y3, ..., yn* over time *t*. I want to find out which of these outcomes *y1, y2, y3, ..., yn* are most affected by *risk* over time *t*, so that I can make a statement like "Units carrying factor risk show the largest increase in y3 and y10 over time".

Setting up multiple single models sounds too simplistic to me (would use  `lmer` or `glmer`, depending on the distribution), but looking at *y1, y2, y3, ..., yn* as joint predictors of *risk* also sounds wrong. Does anyone have an idea?

## Edit:

As suggested by @Peter Flom, I provide some additional information about my data.

- *Risk* is a binary factor.
- y1,...,n_ are discrete (scores) and continuous variables (normalized scores). Theoretically, they could be z-standardized to the same unit (a common practice in my field). Most of the outcomes have the same pattern of missing data, except for 2 variables that were not measured in all units, only starting at *t3*.

```
Data example:
# omitted: more variables, more time points, control variables

UNIT    RISK    TIME    Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4
a   0   0   10  0.2 1   -0.2
a   0   1   10  0.3 1.4 -0.5
a   0   2   10  0.4 1.4 -0.5
a   0   3   10  0.5 1   -0.4
b   1   0   10  0.8 0.9 -0.3
b   1   1   10  1.0 1.6 -0.7
b   1   2   10  1.5 2.0 -0.8
b   1   3   10  1.7 2.8 -1.2
c   1   0   10  0.2 1   -0.4
c   1   1   10  0.6 1   -0.4
c   1   2   10  0.7 3.4 -1.2
c   1   3   10  0.6 4.1 -1.6
```

## Edit 2:

Examining the outcomes in seperate models would yield...

```
model_1 <- lmer(Y1 ~ RISK*Time + covariate + (1|unit), data = dataset)
model_2 <- lmer(Y2 ~ RISK*Time + covariate + (1|unit), data = dataset)
# and so on
```

Initial approach:

- choose *Yn* of `summary(model_n)` where RISK*Time interaction is significant and choose those models with lowest AIC.
- or (additionally) if If *y1, ..., yn* are equally scaled:
  choose *Yn* of `summary(model_n)` with largest betas for RISK*Time interaction....

Comment: It would probably help to know what these outcomes are, whether they are continuous or categorical, whether they are similarly scaled, whether the same missing pattern shows up in each case, and so on.

Comment: Dear @PeterFlom, thanks for your comment. I added some additional information to the post!

Comment: @PeterFlom also added a data example

Comment: It is up to you first to decide how to measure degree of "effect" or "importance." Implicitly the use of a least squares model means you are interested in *magnitudes of differences.* That implies the model with the largest coefficient for $x_i$ is the one that, according to your estimates,"is most affected by" $x_i.$  Implicitly the $y_i$ must measure the same quantity and be comparable: are they?  Because you are contemplating more complicated approaches, I wonder whether you're actually considering a question that differs from the one you have asked.